# How can I combine multiple font files into one family?

Tags: font

I have several font families that have different naming styles. The results is that instead of all those fonts showing up as one family, there's a separate family for each font variation (bold, black, thin, italic, etc).

This makes my font list messy. Is there a way to combine multiple font files into one family?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not afraid about command lines, I suggest you [ttf2ttc](http://ttf2ttc.sourceforge.net/). *.ttc files are [TrueType fonts Collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType#TrueType_Collection)